# Ordenar sin repetir mismo registro SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, orderby

los saludo con gusto y de nuevo recurro a ud's para que me brinden sugerencias de como evitar se repitan los registros en esta consulta SQL Server:

Lo que requiero es saber por cliente/socio las ventas por mes de cada uno de ellos, en esta query solo hago referencia a un solo socio, me muestra los datos pero por mes da un salto de linea y lo que necesito es que plasme en una sola linea con todos los meses la cantidad de ventas por mes, y pares de todo el ese periodo/año.

```
SELECT Tienda, NSocio, Nombre, Ultima_Compra, Fecha_Afil,           
        [1] Enero, [2] Febrero, [3] Marzo, [4] Abril , [5] Mayo, [6] Junio,             
        [7] Julio, [8] Agosto, [9] Septiembre, [10] Octubre, [11] Noviembre, [12] Diciembre, Pares
    FROM (      
SELECT tse.[Store No_] Tienda,tse.[Customer No_] NSocio, c.Name AS Nombre, f.Fecha As Ultima_Compra,
    MONTH([Date]) Mes,          
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR,MAX([Date Created]),103)) AS Fecha_Afil,       
    SUM((tse.[Price]- [Discount Amount])* tse.[Quantity])*(-1) As Total_Mes,        
    COUNT(tse.[Quantity]*-1) As Pares       
    FROM [CIGA$Trans_ Sales Entry] tse  WITH(NOLOCK)        
    INNER JOIN CIGA$Customer c ON c.[No_] = tse.[Customer No_]      
        INNER JOIN  
            (SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,MAX(tse.[Date]),103)) AS Fecha, tse.[Customer No_] AS NSocio
            FROM [CIGA$Trans_ Sales Entry] tse  WITH(NOLOCK) 
            WHERE [Quantity] < 0
            GROUP BY tse.[Customer No_]) As f ON f.NSocio = tse.[Customer No_]
            WHERE [Customer No_]='30003196' AND tse.[Date] 
            BETWEEN '20200101' AND GETDATE() AND [Quantity] < 0 
            AND (c.[No_] LIKE '300%' OR c.[No_] LIKE 'CG008%') AND c.[Name] != ''
            AND [POS Terminal No_] NOT IN ('T0265','T0266')
GROUP BY tse.[Store No_], tse.[Customer No_], c.Name, f.Fecha, [Date Created],MONTH([Date])         
         ) AS SourceTable       
PIVOT (SUM(Total_Mes)  
       FOR Mes IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])  
        ) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es porque no se está agrupando correctamente la consulta al hacer el pivot. Desgraciadamente, esa instrucción es poco flexible y problemática. Mi recomendación es que uses una vieja técnica de agregado condicional. Esto te permite organizar la información más fácilmente.

También reestructuré un poco tu consulta para que esté más organizada.

```
WITH cteUltimasCompras AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,MAX(tse.[Date]),103) AS Fecha, 
            tse.[Customer No_]                  AS NSocio
    FROM [CIGA$Trans_ Sales Entry] tse  WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE [Quantity] < 0
    GROUP BY tse.[Customer No_]
),
cteComprasPorMes AS(
    SELECT  tse.[Store No_]                                             AS Tienda,
            tse.[Customer No_]                                          AS NSocio, 
            c.Name                                                      AS Nombre, 
            f.Fecha                                                     AS Ultima_Compra,
            MONTH([Date])                                               AS Mes,
            (CONVERT(VARCHAR,MAX([Date Created]),103))                  AS Fecha_Afil,
            SUM((tse.[Price]- [Discount Amount])* tse.[Quantity])*(-1)  AS Total_Mes,
            COUNT(tse.[Quantity]*-1)                                    AS Pares
    FROM       [CIGA$Trans_ Sales Entry] AS tse  WITH(NOLOCK)        
    INNER JOIN CIGA$Customer             AS c ON c.[No_]  = tse.[Customer No_]      
    INNER JOIN cteUltimasCompras         As f ON f.NSocio = tse.[Customer No_]
    WHERE [Customer No_]='30003196' 
    AND tse.[Date] BETWEEN '20200101' AND GETDATE() 
    AND [Quantity] < 0 
    AND (c.[No_] LIKE '300%' OR c.[No_] LIKE 'CG008%') 
    AND c.[Name] != ''
    AND [POS Terminal No_] NOT IN ('T0265','T0266')
    GROUP BY tse.[Store No_], tse.[Customer No_], c.Name, f.Fecha, [Date Created],MONTH([Date])
)
SELECT Tienda, 
       NSocio,
       Nombre, 
       Ultima_Compra, 
       Fecha_Afil, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  1 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Enero, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  2 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  3 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Marzo, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  4 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Abril , 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  5 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Mayo, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  6 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Junio,     
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  7 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Julio, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  8 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Agosto, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes =  9 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Septiembre,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes = 10 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Octubre, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes = 11 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Noviembre,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mes = 12 THEN Total_Mes ELSE 0 END) AS Diciembre,
       SUM(Pares) AS Pares
FROM cteComprasPorMes      
GROUP BY Tienda, 
       NSocio,
       Nombre, 
       Ultima_Compra, 
       Fecha_Afil;
```

Comment: Te agradezco la observación, de igual forma estuve consultando como hacer mas efectiva la consulta pero soy novato en esto... saudos y mil gracias por la megacorreccion en la query...

Felices Fiestas bro